# Accessing printer connected to modem, while PC is connected to router

Tags: networking, router, printer, modem

I am having small problem with accessing printer on my network. I have modem located in the attic and my PC and router is connected to it. I can't plug PC into router (for aesthetic reasons), but printer is connected to it. But PC can't see printer (or any other PC) connected to router. Is there a way how to solve it?

Comment: How is this printer "connected" to the router? WiFi? In that case check the printer's and PC's IP addresses. Can you ping them?

Comment: Printeris connected via LAN cable, problem is, that I'm not able to ping anything connected to router

Comment: What are the IP addresses of printer and PCs? For the printer, print a config page; for the PCs, run IPCONFIG from a DOS prompt.